Присвоить id новой записи, которого нед в порядке
При insert, каждой новой записи присваивается последующий id. Если ранее некоторые записи были удалены. Возможно ли по умолчанию выставить в mysql, мол сперва присваиваем id те которых нет...
id
1
2
3
5

Отсутствует 4, добавляем запись, у новой записи id=4,а при добавлении последующих, по порядку, 6,7,8

А Вам зачем это нужно?

Нет, это плохая практика, это ни зачем не нужно, не нужно так делать. Ну, разве что вы массово записи удаляете и у вас числовой диапазон под id заканчивается. Но тогда проще повысить тип id до более широкого диапазона. А чтобы исчерпать самый большой диапазон нужно очень постараться.

Возможно ли по умолчанию выставить в mysql, мол сперва присваиваем id те которых нет... Если речь об автоматическом получении пропущенного автоинкрементного значения - однозначно нет. Если о программном поиске такого значения и явном присвоении его в записи - то да, но так лучше не делать по причинам, разъяснённым выше.

Это вопрос из любопытства или нужно решить какую-то другую задачу?

В целом, вопрос решаем, но с одним но - делать это не для первичного ключа..... или,  во всяком случае не для автоинкрементного, а для другого поля в таблице

Пытаюсь закрыть дыры в цепочке ключей. Не понимаю, при записе если указать какой именно id должен быть. То все хорошо и lastid() при insert возвращает. Не понимаю, почему не стоит этого делать? Все же работает на ура...

"Пытаюсь закрыть дыры в цепочке ключей" - ну, с какой целью? Зачем это вам?

Часто удаляю новости, которые доступны по id в url. Дабы не терять трафик, заменить другими публикациями...

То есть по ссылке будет лежать всё-равно не то, зачем человек пришёл?  Во-первых непонятно, зачем тогда удаляете вообще. Во-вторых перенастройте сайт, чтобы если пришли за несуществующей новостью, то показывалось что-то из главных новостей. Мне кажется вы не то лечите, что нужно.
